# Why doesn't grep return the whole line in this case?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, grep

I am practicing using the terminal in Mac OSX.

I went to the `/dev/` folder from root, and wanted to look for the line containing `null`, so I did `ls` to get the folder contents. There was a lot, so I saw this as an opportunity to use `grep`. So I typed `ls | grep "null"` and simply got back `null` instead of the full line `null                 ttyp9` as shown in the normal `ls` listing.

Why is this happening? I thought `grep` returned full lines?

Comment: Why `ls` or `grep`, just use `printf "%s\n" *null*`

Comment: FYI, [parsing the output of ls is generally considered bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/578242/how-to-combine-ls-and-grep-to-list-only-files-and-using-ls-to-count-dirs Of course, if you're just learning it is a good way to practice, because of all the weird cases you can run into :)

Comment: @whrrgarbl Yes, just learning. Thanks for those links

Comment: @whrrgarbl Reading that link... What?! I didn't realize Unix was so lenient with the characters allowed in filenames.

Comment: @ArukaJ Anything but `/` and NUL is allowed in a filename I believe.

Comment: @EtanReisner So would it be better to grep something like `find` instead if you wanted to look for filenames?

Comment: Why not just `ls /dev/null`?

Comment: @ArukaJ - no, parsing `find` doesn't work all the time either.  Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for explanations and strategies. (hint: use a `for` loop, and `globstar` if you need recursion.)

Comment: @ghoti I don't know how you can write multi-line code like that in the terminal

Comment: @ArukaJ, try `printf 'Hello\nworld.\n'` And in a filename, `touch $'foo\nbar'`.

Comment: If your command isn't finished when you hit enter you get a newline and a secondary prompt and you can just keep going with the command.

Comment: @ghoti I read http://www.tecmint.com/manage-linux-filenames-with-special-characters/ but don't see what it means to have the dollar sign outside the filename like that?

Comment: @ArukaJ - that's a bashism, described here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Comment: But if I omit the $ it still seems to make the same file (folder?) name `foo\nbar`

Comment: Using `ls -C` gives you columnar output even if the output is redirected to a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ttyp9` is a **different** file.

`ls` is showing you columns of output.

When not sent to the terminal `ls` doesn't do that and acts as if you used the `-1` argument.

Comment: So `grep` doesn't return lines as they're displayed with the output (in this case columns of text with `ls`) but in some kind of linear fashion? Or rather the column thing is something outside of `ls`?

Comment: No, `grep` does return the lines it gets. The lines *you* get and the lines `grep` gets are different here though. Run `ls -1` and you'll see what `grep` is seeing.

Comment: The column output is something `ls` does when displaying to the terminal to make it easier for *people* to see many files at once. It also "knows" that other tools can't handle that (and shouldn't have to) so it *defaults* to different behavior in the case where its output is a terminal and when its output isn't. See the difference between `ls` and `ls | cat` for example.

Comment: Tried `man ls` to see what `-1` meant. "Force output to be one entry per line. This is the default when output is not to a terminal." Makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`grep` does return full lines. The `ls` command by itself does not give details. Try this instead:

```
ls -l | grep "null"
```

That listing flag gives more details, which grep can then return.

In other words, `grep` was doing what you wanted it to, there was just nothing there to see.

The `ls` command without options will just show filenames. Typically the returned list of filenames is wrapped. You can unwrap them if you type:

```
ls -1
```

If you look at this listing, you will see that `null` is actually on a line all by itself.

If you add the `long listing` option:

```
ls -l
```

You will see much more detail. The `grep` command can only return what is given to it, and the in this case `ls` is what is supplying all the inputs for grep.

Comment: Not the details he's looking for.