# Does the pipeline modify the separator of words?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipeline

I have a confusion about pipeline operation. E.g.:

```
# ls *.cfg
anaconda-ks.cfg  initial-setup-ks.cfg
# ls *.cfg | cat
anaconda-ks.cfg
initial-setup-ks.cfg
```

When executing `ls` operation only, it displays items separated by blank space (or tab):

```
anaconda-ks.cfg  initial-setup-ks.cfg
```

But through the pipeline, it seems the space is replaced by the new line:

```
anaconda-ks.cfg
initial-setup-ks.cfg
```

How to understand it? Is it the pipeline that modify the separator?

Comment: I just answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35924342/258523).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [man page for `ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html) gives you your answer:

> If standard output is a terminal, the output is in columns (sorted vertically) and control characters are output as question marks; otherwise, the output is listed one per line and control characters are output as-is.

When piping to another command, your output is not a terminal (i.e. an interactive login session.)